# Memory Leak(?) when displaying images in java

Tags: java, image, memory-leaks

today I kinda fiddled around with image opening/scaling/displaying in Java and wrote a bit of code to open an Image File, scale it randomly and display it for a short time.

The problem is: After displaying it for like 100-1000 times, the used memory of my "javaw.exe" grows and grows, it even reached 1 GB of memory space.

I dont know where the memory leak in my code is since the only memory eating things are my picures and there are only 2 (the original image and the one who is getting scaled, which is always assigned to the same variable(temp) so the "older" ones should be picked off by the GC), maybe you guys could have a look over it, its pretty simple.

1) You choose an image from your hard drive

2) It gets scaled randomly

3) Its displayed for a short amount of time and then disappears

4) go to 2)

To scale the image I used this library: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(chooser.getSelectedFile());
    BufferedImage temp;


    while(true){

        int width = (int) ((Math.random()*1000)+1); 
        int height = (int) ((Math.random()*1000)+1);

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        temp = Scalr.resize(originalImage,Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, width, height);


        showImage(temp, 800);

    }

}

static void showImage(BufferedImage v,long length) throws InterruptedException {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(v)));
    frame.setSize(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());

    frame.setVisible(true);
    Thread.sleep(length);
    frame.setVisible(false);


}
```

This is my first time posting here, so please ask questions if I am unclear

thanks in advance!

EDIT: I monitored the memory javaw.exe is needing

1 picture displayed: 75M
100 pictures displayed: 330M
1000 pictures displayed: 2,4G

EDIT 2:

I now have applied your helpful advice but I still have a growing amount of memory and my Images arent displayed anymore.. The JFrames are empty.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        BufferedImage temp;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();


        while(true){

            int width = (int) ((Math.random()*1000)+1); 
            int height = (int) ((Math.random()*1000)+1);

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            temp = Scalr.resize(originalImage,Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, width, height);


            showImage(temp, 500, frame);

        }

    }

    static void showImage(BufferedImage v,long length, JFrame frame) throws InterruptedException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                () -> {


                    frame.removeAll();
                    frame.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();

                    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(v)));
                    frame.setSize(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());

                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(length);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    frame.setVisible(false);

                    frame.dispose();
                });



    }

}
```

Maybe I put your advice in the wrong places in my code.

Comment: How much memory are you giving Java? Does it eventually run out of memory, or does garbage collection eventually kick in?

Comment: You're creating new frames in a loop but never close them (you merely make them invisible), and each one has a resized image. You should be getting memory leaks. Garbage collection can never happen as long as those frames are around. Also, you're on the main thread. This is never going to work, you will eventually run out of memory and crash the VM.

Comment: You probably have to modify the vm config file and give it more memory.

Comment: @hagubear This problem has nothing to do with VM memory. The code is simply HIDING JFrames with the images in them. This is an application logic problem. Nothing is ever going to be garbage collected.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even see the showImage() method. Try calling frame.dispose() instead of frame.setVisible(false). That way the frame's resources are freed instead of just hidden.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I am giving the JVM the devault value of memory, but this amount is not my problem since i have 16G of memory, the problem is the increasing number of memory needed. Thanks for the hint with frame.dispose() !

Comment: @mttdbrd thanks! ill close the frames, that should fix a part of my problem. what do you mean "you are on the main thread"? should i make a new thread for every image and then end it?

Comment: @LBecker No, you should be on the EDT. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: @LBecker Katerina A's answer shows how to get on the event dispatch thread.

Comment: @mttdbrd hey, could you have another look at my code? I now have applied your advices but strangely the re-use of the frame doesnt work right and since the point I have put my Jframe-display logic into the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() the image isnt displayed properly, it worked before.

Comment: @LBecker Check out my answer. I'm not too sure about this library because the docs seem to contradict what the code says for FIT_EXACT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do what you want. I used a Timer instead of Thread.sleep. You're tying up the EDT. I also just draw the image in the container. You should probably use a JPanel instead (add it to the JFrame and override its paintComponent method). I also cleaned up the methods a little.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public class App extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        BufferedImage originalImage = null;
        BufferedImage temp = null;
        JFileChooser chooser = null;

        public App(){

                setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                                () -> {
                                        App app = new App();

                                        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, app);
                                        timer.start();

                                });

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                if(null == chooser){
                        chooser = new JFileChooser();
                        chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
                        loadImage();
                }
                showImage();
                repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
                super.paint(g);
                if(null == temp){
                        return;
                }
                g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);
        }

        public void loadImage(){

                try{
                        originalImage = ImageIO.read(chooser.getSelectedFile());
                } catch(IOException ioe){
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public void showImage() {
                int width = (int) ((Math.random()*1000)+1); 
                int height = (int) ((Math.random()*1000)+1);
                temp = Scalr.resize(originalImage,Scalr.Mode.BEST_FIT_BOTH, width, height);
                setSize(width, height);
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
originalImage.flush();
originalImage = null;
temp.flush();
temp = null;
```

but there is no guarantee when your image will get garbage collected

Apart from that you should also consider clearing and reusing the same JFrame.

```
removeAll();//or remove the previous JLabel
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Also the proper way to display a JFrame is by using the SwingUtilities invokeLater method to make sure this "job" is placed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

```
 // schedule this for the event dispatch thread (edt)
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(yourJFrame);
```

Comment: This won't work because he's keeping the JFrames around. Those need to be cleaned up. AND it's on the main application thread. That also needs to be fixed. I'll upvote if you can fix all the problems.

Comment: @KaterinaA. alright, thanks for this help but I am currently unclear where to insert this helpful code. I edited my original post to show the new version of my program